Segment API issues - Adding members to segment not getting reflected
I created segment from my local machine using Banno segment API. It created successfully and i was able to validate it in UI
Next, I tried adding members to the segment created above. I am using the <https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/segments/details/#/CSV/post_a_segments_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__segments__segmentId__import API> to add members to the segment i created in step 1.
curl --request POST 'https://banno.com/a/segments/api/v0/institutions/1234/segments/eba9970a-7387-4dbb-844f-1212121212/import?sourceType=netteller_id&operationType=append' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--form 'sourceProvider="Some Bank"' \
--form 'file=@"/Documents/segment_members.csv"' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>'

{"csvHeaders":["netTellerId"],"csvUnknownRows":[],"draftId":"121212-ecc8-4a17-befb-0ddef9f8ce41","foundUsersCount":2,"operationCount":4}

As you can see I do get a success response. But when I check in the UI, I am not seeing the members in the segment, It just shows 0 users.

In order too see the changes reflected to your segment there is an additional step - in the response you shared there is a draftId - you then need to send an additional request to the PUT /a/segments/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/segments/{segmentId}/drafts/{draftId} endpoint, this will actually append the users to a segment.
If successful you should see the updates reflected in the UI.

Thanks Sam. that answers my question
